# Rails form_for that uses STI base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, inheritance, polymorphic-associations, sti

I've got a pretty simple (I think) single-table inheritance (STI) setup in my Rails app.

There is a User model with a nested resource Post.
Using STI, I have it so that some Posts can be Post::Urgent objects.

I noticed that my URL helpers like `<%= [@user, @post] %>` needed to be hard-coded to `<%= user_post_path[@user, @post] %>` or else I'd end up seeing errors about Rails not finding the `user_post_urgent_path` method. Okay, that was reasonably easy.

(An alternate way of doing this is also `<%= [@user, post: @post] %>`.)

Well, for some reason I'm not able to figure out how to make the `form_for` method adjusted in the same way. When I write simply

```
<%= form_for [@user, @post] do |f| %>
```

, I get similar errors to the URL helper case, but in the form context: `undefined method 'user_post_urgen_path'`.

I fixed this by specifying:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @post], url: :user_post do |f| %>
```

But this doesn't completely work, because when I go to submit the form, I get problems in my controller, saying that strong parameters line `params.require(:post)` failed:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: post
```

If I inspect the `params` I find that the form is passing a `post_urgent` object and not a `post` object.

I could, of course, manually put in some logic that always says `if !params[:post] and params[:post_urgent], then params[:post] = params[:post_urgent]`. But that just seems *way* too hacky, especially for Rails.

Is there a better way to make a form like this "just work" regardless of what subclass of the Post model it actually happens to be?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not sure if you found a solution already, but I am using the following for my forms

```
= form_for [@user, @post.becomes(Post)] do |f|
  - f.object = @post.becomes @post.class
```

reference: http://thepugautomatic.com/2012/08/rails-sti-and-form-for/

Comment: It works, but Yuck! Seems like there should be a better way, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had some nested models initialized in the controller, empty unsaved models to work with `accepts_nested_attribues_for` and `becomes` empties them for some reason, so instead, I acted on the controller strong params, not the cleanest, I know.

```
  def unpermitted_model_params
    polymorphic_form_params = params.to_unsafe_hash
        .slice('sub_model1', 'sub_model2')
    form_values = polymorphic_form_params.first.to_a.second
    ActionController::Parameters.new(parent_model: form_values)
  end

  def allowed_params
    unpermitted_model_params.require(:parent_model)
                            .permit(:type, :etc, :etc)
  end
```